# Background Sound in Dr-Racket [lang #r5rs]

Tags: loops, audio, scheme, racket

I am trying to use some background sound in a game. If i use the loop i currently have it doesn't return or it layers the sound. Is there a way to test of there is sound playing in the ui or is the Rsound a must have for sounds?

---

```
(define play-asynchronously #f)

(define sound-test #t)
(define (sound-test!)
  (if sound-test
      #f
      #t))



(define (in-game-loop)
  (if sound-test
      (if (play-sound "flight_of_the_bumblebee.mp3" play-asynchronously)
          ;Geschreven in 1899-1900 door Nikolaj Rimski-Korsakov
          ;Gedownload op 16/05/2018 van https://ia802606.us.archive.org/19/items/FlightOfTheBumblebee/flight_of_the_bumblebee_2.mp3
          (in-game-loop)
          'done)
      (begin
        (in-menu-loop)
        (set! sound-test #t))))

(define (in-menu-loop)
  (if sound-test
      (if (play-sound "Gymnopedie-No-1.mp3" play-asynchronously)
          ;Geschreven in 1888 door Erik Satie
          ;Gedownload op 16/05/018 van https://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/?keywords=gymnopedie
          (in-menu-loop)
          'done)
      (begin
        (in-game-loop)
        (set! sound-test #t))))
```

---

Comment: Code formatting: Select the code, then press the curly-brackets icon or Ctrl-k (Command-k on a Mac).

Comment: Side notes: identifiers ending in "!" are usually only used for procedures that mutate something (such as `set!`). And `(if e #f #t)` is `(not e)`.